# Is there a function in R where I can print the only other unique element in a row?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a seriously confusing problem that I'd like to get help on.

I have the following data table:

| type | value |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 1 |
| dog | 0 |
| cat | 1 |
| cat | 1 |
| cat | 1 |
| dog | 0 |

There are only two unique values in the column type. I want to mutate a new column where I search for the value 0, but then print cat, which is the only other unique value in the type column, and not a dog. As so,

| type | value | mutated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 1 | _ |
| dog | 0 | cat |
| cat | 1 | _ |
| cat | 1 | _ |
| cat | 1 | _ |
| dog | 0 | cat |

I have no clue where to start. I've tried `ifelse` statements but they fail to print the opposite of the value in that row. Any help?

Here's a function I've tried:

```
data %>% mutate(mutated = ifelse(value == 0, !(type), type))
```

However, that just gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setdiff`, which will take the difference between a vector of all `type` (which is length of 2, just "cat" and "dog") and the `type` for a given row. There are other ways to approach this depending on what you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mutated = ifelse(value == 0, setdiff(unique(df$type), type), "-"))
```

**Output**

```
  type  value mutated
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  
1 cat       1 -      
2 dog       0 cat    
3 cat       1 -      
4 cat       1 -      
5 cat       1 -      
6 dog       0 cat
```

Comment: Fantastic solution and explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(mutated = ifelse(value == 0, "cat", "-"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  type  value mutated
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  
1 cat       1 -      
2 dog       0 cat    
3 cat       1 -      
4 cat       1 -      
5 cat       1 -      
6 dog       0 cat
```

## Your data

```
dput(df)
structure(list(type = c("cat", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat", "dog"
), value = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```